# Execute ScheduledJob with elevated rights

Tags: powershell

I want to install WSUS updates on my servers, remotely. I created a scheduled job on all my servers and I want to use ScheduledJob (not ScheduledTasks because I want to manage Windows Server 2008 R2 and ScheduledTasks cmdlets are not supported). So, I created a scheduled job:

```
$option = New-ScheduledJobOption -RunElevated
Register-ScheduledJob -Name "Installation Updates" -ScheduledJobOption $option -ScriptBlock { #MyScript }
```

Now, I want to run this scheduled job:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
    $startJob = (Get-ScheduledJob | ? { $_.Name -like "Installation Updates" }).StartJob()
}
```

A job is launched (I see it with `Get-Job` and I have a txt file output), but the installation of the updates doesn't work, because not enough rights. The creation and the execution of the scheduled job are made with a Domain Admin account.

If I start powershell "as an Administrator" on the server with this account, and I test the command (whitout `Invoke-Command`), it works.

Why doesn't `.StartJob()` work in a normal PowerShell session? I have the option "RunElevated" in the scheduled job. Anyone have an idea to do this? I tried on Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows Server 2016, same problem.

**EDIT 1:** I tried the cmdlet `Start-Job`, same problem, the installation of the updates doesn't work, because not enough rights:

```
$startJob = Start-Job -DefinitionName "Installation des Updates"
```

Comment: if u want to use scheduled task using command-lets, then use this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/schtasks, You can use ("/RL", "HIGHEST") for "Run with highest privileges". Is this what you looking for ?

Comment: Wow, great idea ! I will test that. I keep you inform :)

Comment: IT WORKS !!!! Thank you Tech Gaurdian !

`code`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
schtasks.exe /Run /I /TN "Installation Updates"
}

Comment: Can I put this as a solution, will u mark this as an answer?

Comment: I marked it ! :)

Comment: Thanks ShadowMaso!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scheduled task using command-lets, then use the link below :

[learn.microsoft.com-windows-schtasks](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/schtasks)

which enables an administrator to modify scheduled tasks

(or also you can use `("/RL", "HIGHEST")` for `Run with highest privileges`)

Hope this helps !!